# BES 5 Upgrade: How do I determine current service pack level?

Tags: blackberry, bes

In Blackberry Enterprise Manager it says our server is at 4.1.6.10, but there is no indication of service pack level. I'm going through the upgrade guide for version 5 and it says we need at least 4.1 SP3 to upgrade. Where can I find this information?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd number is always the SP you are on.
So 4.1.6 is Version 4.1 SP6

You can get the MR you are on from the Add/Remove programs, in the About link.  The .10 is the build which represents the MR, but they don't match up to MR1, MR2 etc.  .10 is pretty low so I'm suspecting that is either MR1 or just the SP6.

I'd also suggest installing 5.0 as a stand alone trial first.  Its quite a bit different for the UI so you may want to get familiar with it first and also glitches you might run into.